# .Htaccess Url Rewrite Replace %20 (Space) with "-"

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am trying to edit mt .htaccess rewrite url.

this is my url :
http://www.indojamtangan.com/jamtanganoriginal/Alexandre%20Christie

Alexandre Christie is my brand parameter. i want to make my .htaccess url to http://www.indojamtangan.com/jamtanganoriginal/Alexandre-Christie . i want replace %20 with - . i have trying every code from other topics on Stackoverflow but everything didnt work.

this is my htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^brand/([a-z0-9/s]+)$ /brand.php?brand=$1 [L]
```

where code should i modify to make my goal possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\?cat_type=(.*)&location=(.*)%(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://your_domain.com/%3/%4/%5-%6? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\?location=(.*)%(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://your_domain.com/%3/%4-%5? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your answer, i tried your code but still didnt work.

i put your code above my code before on the top post. (domain edited with my domai) is it still wrong?
i try to access http://www.indojamtangan,com/alexandre christie but it still apear tu %20 on the space